# Substring length doesn't add up

Tags: postgresql, substring, string-length

I have the following i'm running to trim a UK postcode unit down to a UK postcode sector where a full unit might be AA11 1AB or A1 1AB and i want AA11 1 and A1 1 returned respectively;

```
UPDATE record1 
SET new_col = substring (record1.original_col,0, (length(original_col) - 2));
```

As a test i run `select substring ('w1 0js',0, (length('w1 0js') - 2));`and this returns `w1` not `w1 0` The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)  say `length` is the number of characters so why am i getting this result?

Comment: The first character has the position `1` not `0`

Comment: Thank you, i was following http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-substring/ which says ' If start_position equals zero, the substring starts at the first character of the string.' which i'd read as me needing to use 0

Answer (score 0):

To select all but the last two characters, use:

```
UPDATE record1 
SET    new_col = left(record1.original_col, -2);
```